# Installing Sweave for Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, sweave

I've been looking everywhere, but my computer (Windows 7) just won't install the `Sweave.sty` package for Miktex 2.9. I tried to put it in a folder respecting the TDS standard, and then to install it, locally. The Package Manager won't accept any folder I suggest as a local package repository

> error: this folder doesn't seem to be a local repository.

I added the direction to the roots, but it just won't find the `sweave.sty` package. I updated the database several times, with the texhash prompt in the console, and using the button.

I tried to follow the instructions on: 
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/229033.html
and http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html

It always gives me the same error message:

> Package Sweave could not be found.

On my other computer I have a local repository in the User folder, and I always have to put the directory of the Sweave file in the preamble of my document. At least, that works, but as I would like to keep my file reproducible, I would prefer to know how to properly install Sweave. Maybe its because I changed the basic directory shown in the console to the local folder where my LaTeX document is.

I use the WinEdt editor. Maybe it has something to do with Ghostscript, I have no idea whether this is installed or what it is used for. I try to find out about that next.

Can anyone give me a hint what to try next? I tried to be as precise as I could.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://$SITEURL$/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Never heard of this WinEditor, what is it?

Comment: @karlkoeller I guess the correct name is WinEdt 6, it is my editor. Probably an alternative to the TeXnicCenter described in the solution that I posted.

Comment: Oh well, I thought it was WinEdt, but googling I've found an editor called WinEditor and I had a doubt... Anyway, if you want to use Sweave with WinEdt, have a look at the [R-Sweave](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/R-Sweave.php) add-on. In the help you will also find instructions on how to setup Sweave to work from within WinEdt.

Comment: This is probably the five hundred and seventy-eighth time that people have asked about the very confusing `Sweave.sty`. Why not forget about it and use the `knitr` package instead?

Comment: @Yihui I found a lot of questions similar to mine, and for all the others the standard root solution worked out.  I will try out knitr, it must be my system as the local root solution works out on the other computer.

Comment: May be this answer is useful for setting up local tex tree: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484)

Answer (score 3):

I finally changed all my documents to knitr, now everything works fine, even if I lost a lot of time. My problem was not adding the roots to my database, but I didn't find out what it was. The Database updating worked out on the other computer, but my computer just won't install Sweave.

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is to create a local TEXMF tree in MiKTeX, for example in the directory `C:\Local`.

After that, create the path `C:\Local\tex\latex\misc` and copy `Sweave.sty` there.

At this point, open the admin version of MiKTeX Settings program, and, in the 'Roots' tab, press 'Add' and select the directory `C:\Local`. Now press 'OK' and MiKTeX automatically inserts `C:\Local` in the TDS as a local tree.

If you now add the line

```
\usepackage{Sweave}
```

in your document, Sweave is found by MiKTeX.

Moreover, since you are using WinEdt as your editor, I suggest you to download the [R-Sweave](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/R-Sweave.php) add-on by Gilbert Ritschard that lets you use Sweave from within WinEdt (a very useful package). The version for WinEdt 7/8 also adds support for knitr, if you're interested in it.

Comment: I found and tried out this solution before. I swear I did what you said, it still won't work out. I found that solution in different blogs, too. It didn't work using [link](C:\LocalTexFiles) instead of [link](C:\Local) neither. I will, however, update my WinEdt version and install the addon. Then, I will try out knitr.