# Reinstalling LaTeX in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installing, sweave

The LaTeX in my system cannot support Sweave compilation to `pdflatex`, it warns for missing `.sty` files. I want to clean my system and reinstall a more complete LaTeX. What is the better way for doing so?

Comment: There are a few post on installing vanilla TeXLive on Ubuntu floating around.  My post here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120120/does-texlive2013-need-any-special-install-instructions has a link to how you uninstall the older version and install the new one.  The information is in the first answer.

Comment: Note that `Sweave` has to be installed separately. It is a part of every `R` installation. See its [homepage](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/)

Comment: [Again](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117621/installing-sweave-for-miktex-2-9-on-windows-7#comment261263_117621), that is the penalty of not using `knitr`.

Answer (score 5):

Requirements :  Ubuntu 13.04 and previous versions.

**Uninstalling Latex:**

Open your terminal and past the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge
```

---

**Installing Latex:**

They are currently 2 possibilities. You can first decide to install latex via official repository. Be aware that this version has not been updated recently.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Or, you can download the **last updated texlive** source tar.gz at this

< **[link](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz)** >

---

Then I suggest you to install a good editor, like [texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) :

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Let me know if you encounter any problem.

Comment: It's a bad idea to install TeX Live by apt-get. The version is outdated. It's always the best to install TeX Live from here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You are definitely right. It was just for the record.