# How can I build a LaTeX file with fourier-ms?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fourier

I am trying to compile the following file with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
$p<0.05$
\end{document}
```

I get the following error.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+552/600 --dpi 552 fourier-ms
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fourier-ms.
mktexpk: perhaps fourier-ms is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fourier-ms): Font fourier-ms at 552 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have downloaded and installed [this package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fourier-GUT/?lang=en), but I still get the error.

**How can I build this LaTeX file?**

Here is the output of `pdflatex -v`.

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0
```

Comment: Why do you think that you need such a map?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Based on other solutions found on the internet, I tried to run `updmap --enable Map=fourier-ms.map` and ran into troubles with not having the map file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I have fixed the question after finding the MWE.

Comment: Works fine for me on a current texlive -- and I don't have a fourier-ms.map. The map you should enable is fourier.map.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue seemed due to a faulty installation of TeX Live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a variety of things but the only solution that worked was to reinstall latex based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122886/24402) and then run `updmap`.

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge
sudo apt-get install texlive-full  
updmap
```